# How to block a user for specific time after 3 attempts?

Tags: java, servlets, java-ee-6

I've created a simple login servlet in which the user enters his email and password and it checks if he's a registered user then it logs him in , if he's not it says login fail,the credentials are stored in a text file , I can't use a database,the code works perfect.
Now the only problem is that I'm trying to block a registered user after 3 attempts for a specific period of time , let's say 30 mins , how can that be done ?

The format of the text file is as follows :

- example@mail.com,password
- example2@mail.com,password2

The email and password are seperated by a ','

CODE :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletConfig;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
//int attempts = 3;
/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5498866193863633001L;

/**
 * HashMap to store all users credentials
 */
private final Map<String, String> credentialsPairs = new HashMap<> 
();

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    String delimiter = ",";
    String line = "";

    /**
     * Credentials file will be there in WEB-INF directory as it 
provide secured
     * access only.
     */
    String credentialFile = "/WEB-INF/accounts.txt";

    /**
     * Read the file and prepare Map with username as key and 
password as value We
     * have put this code in init method as it is called once only 
that will avoid
     * overhead of iterating values from file for each request
     */
    InputStream is = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();

    try {
        /**
         * Open stream of file
         */
        is = context.getResourceAsStream(credentialFile);
        if (is != null) {
            /**
             * Read the file line by line and store email as a key 
   and password as value
             */
            isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] credentials = line.split(delimiter);
                // credentials[0] is email and credentials[1] is 
   password
                credentialsPairs.put(credentials[0], 
   credentials[1]);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
            if (isr != null) {
                isr.close();
            }
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
 response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    /**
     * Get user entered credentials
     */
    String userEmail = request.getParameter("email");
    String userPassword = request.getParameter("password");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    boolean isValidUser = false;

    /**
     * Get value from Map for user entered email address.
     */
    String password = credentialsPairs.get(userEmail);

    /**
     * If User with entered email address found then we will get 
   password for that
     * user
     */
    if (password != null) {
        /**
         * Compare password entered by user with one that is 
   retrieved from file
         */
        if (password.equals(userPassword)) {
            isValidUser = true;
        }
    }
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if (isValidUser) {
            //HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("email", userEmail);
            
  request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp").include(request, 
  response);
            //response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
        }
        else {
            int loginAttempt;
            if (session.getAttribute("loginCount") == null)
            {
                session.setAttribute("loginCount", 0);
                loginAttempt = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                loginAttempt = (Integer) 
   session.getAttribute("loginCount");
            }

            //this is 3 attempt counting from 0,1,2
            if (loginAttempt >= 2 )
            {
                long lastAccessedTime = 
    session.getLastAccessedTime();
                Date date = new Date();
                long currentTime = date.getTime();
                long timeDiff = currentTime - lastAccessedTime;
                // 20 minutes in milliseconds
                if (timeDiff >= 1200000)
                {
                    //invalidate user session, so they can try 
    again
                    session.invalidate();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Error message
                    session.setAttribute("message","You have 
             exceeded the 3 failed login attempt. Please try loggin 
             in in 20 minutes.");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                loginAttempt++;
                int allowLogin = 3-loginAttempt;
                session.setAttribute("message","loginAttempt= 
      "+loginAttempt+". Invalid username or password. You have 
    "+allowLogin+" attempts remaining. Please try again! <br>Not a 
    registered cusomer? Please <a 
  href=\"register.jsp\">register</a>!");
            }
            session.setAttribute("loginCount",loginAttempt);
        }
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
  }

public void destroy() {
    /**
     * Free up the map
     */
    credentialsPairs.clear();
}
}
```

Comment: "I can't use a database" is this homework? Because a naive solution would be to keep that information in memory. Of course you will lose it after a restart, but if it's homework it shouldn't matter much. If it's an actual application I have many more questions, especially for the cleartext passwords in a text file.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca this is an assignment so I'm kinda under restrictions

Answer (score 0):

You should add one more properties in credentialsPairs like ,
then when you check password also check the time of login for blocking the user

Answer (score 0):

Create an object in the user's session.  Call it trackLogOns.  Put a timestamp when on the object the first time the user attempts to log in but fails.  Also, put an integer on the object for tracking the times the user tries and fails to log on.  Check the session for the object every time the user logs on.  If the object exists but the timer is longer than 120, delete the session object and create a new one and proceed with the logic below.  If the object exists and it's less than 120 you'll increment the counter and act accordingly.  E.g.  The counter is less than 3 just increment the counter.  If the counter is 3 or more, stop the user.

If you are trying to do this and the user has not logged in, put it in the variable at the application level or context scope.  Then the application can keep track of it.  Here's a link to help you understand the length that variables can survive based on the scope of where they are placed.  As you may or may not know you can place variables in memory at the page level, request level, session level, and application level.  Application level is probably used the least however in this case I think you'd need that level.  Here's a link to help you understand it more.

https://www.javajee.com/application-request-session-and-page-scopes-in-servlets-and-jsps

Comment: I kinda did what you said , but am getting an error , even after debugging I can't get where the error at ,

Comment: I've edited the question